# Displaying delete button only if the logged in user has ADMIN authority in react

Tags: reactjs, web-applications

What is the best way to show a delete button on a component in react only when the logged in user is an `ADMIN`

My `Member` entity is saved to postgres from Springboot backend `private String authority;`

I can see that this authority is passed to react with a redux logger and when logged in it shows ADMIN.

as part of a userlistItem which shows cards for all the members, there is a view and delete button. The view button is fine for all to see, but I only want ADMIN users to be able to see and delete a member.

So far I have tried the following, checking if the logged in user authority = ADMIN

`const isAdmin = props.user.authority === "ADMIN";`

then using this in the code to decide if the display the button, only displaying it if isAdmin = true

```
               <div className="card-body">
                    <div className="float-left btn-group btn-group-sm">
                    <Link
                        to={`/${props.user.username}`}>
                            <button  className="btn btn-primary tooltips float-left" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="view"><i className="fa fa-eye"></i> </button>
                    </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="float-right btn-group btn-group-m">
                    {isAdmin && (
                            <button  className="btn btn-secondary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete"><i className="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                    )}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to check and display this correctly. This is the full class for the userlistitem

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const UserListItem = (props) => {
    const isAdmin = props.user.authority === "ADMIN";
  
  return (
            <div className="card col-12">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <div className="col-4">
                        <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar7.png" alt="" className="img-fluid rounded-circle w-60"></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 card-title align-self-center mb-0">
                        <h5>{props.user.firstname} {props.user.surname}</h5>
                        <p className="m-0">Handicap : {props.user.handicap}</p>
                        <p className="m-0">Role : {props.user.authority}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li className="list-group-item"><i className="fa fa-envelope float-right"></i>Email : {props.user.email}</li>
                        <li className="list-group-item"><i className="fa fa-phone float-right"></i>Mobile : {props.user.mobile}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <div className="float-left btn-group btn-group-sm">
                    <Link
                        to={`/${props.user.username}`}>
                            <button  className="btn btn-primary tooltips float-left" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="view"><i className="fa fa-eye"></i> </button>
                    </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="float-right btn-group btn-group-m">
                    {isAdmin && (
                            <button  className="btn btn-secondary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete"><i className="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                    )}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
    
  );
};

export default UserListItem;
```

I have ran this on another page and if I print out `isAdmin` it is working and shows true when the logged in user is admin otherwise false.

Comment: I think it should be changed to an array , like `isAllowed=['ADMIN'].includes(role)` ,but overall seems workable and not really an issue at scale even

Comment: Thanks, it's currently not working in its current form. What would the role parameter represent in your example? Would I use something like isAllowed = ['ADMIN'].includes(user.authority) would that then check if user.authority is the same as ADMIN?

Comment: `const [isAdmin,setIsAdmin] = useState(props.user.authority === "ADMIN")` `useEffect(()=>{setIsAdmin(props.user.authority === "ADMIN")},[props.user.authority])`

Answer (score 0):

```
const [isAuthorized,setIsAuthorized] = useState(['ADMIN'].includes(props.user.authority));
useEffect(()=>{
      setIsAuthorized(['ADMIN'].includes(props.user.authority))
     },[props.user.authority])
```

majorly what seems wrong with your code (best practices kept aside), is that you have assigned a variable `isAdmin` a value directly , now underneath the hood the value of isAdmin might change but react isn't checking for it. So , make sure that you are using `useState` for dynamic values . Apart from that if you have a feature which in future might be provided as a service to end users but currently is being reserved for `admin` only then  I would also suggest that the list of `isAuthorized` comes from backend , so that it is easier fo you to make it available for `end users` and dynamically services could be organised easily  as well.